# How to chain queries in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, activerecord

I used to do something like this in code Igniter

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from($this::DB_TABLE);
 if ($role == "manager") {
    $this->db->where('is_manager',1);
 }
 if ($role == "staff") {
     $this->db->where('is_staff',1);
 }
 $this->db->where('is_active', 1);
 $this->db->order_by('last_name', 'asc');
 $user_set = $this->db->get();
 return $user_set;
```

How can I write a similar query like this in laravel 5. I new to laravel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to conditionally change the query parameters it's like:

```
$query = Model::select('*')
if ($role == "manager") {
    $query = $query->where('is_manager',1);
}
if ($role == "staff") {
    $query = $query->where('is_staff',1);
}
$user_set = $query->where('is_active', 1)->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')->get();

return $user_set;
```

But I think it would be more succinct like this (totally untested, but I think this would work):

```
return  Model::select('*')
    ->where('is_manager', $role == 'manager' ? 1 : 0)
    ->where('is_staff', $role == 'staff' ? 1 : 0)
    ->where('is_active', 1)
    ->orderBy('last_name', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @jcorry. I will try it and see

Comment: negating of condition is not the same as omitting it

Answer (score 3):

Yeah but we have this pretty great Eloquent ORM that didn't exist in Codeigniter.

Now it looks like:

```
Model::where('is_manager', 1)->where('is_active', 1)->orderBy('last_name', 'DESC')->get()
```

It's similar, but WAY more powerful.

Study the [Eloquent docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) and check out some of the basic examples in the Laracasts tutorials.

Comment: The [Query Builder Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) are also something that should be read as Eloquent builds upon that.

Comment: Thanks jcorry. I know how I can modify my code to work with your query. It's possible to build a query and add conditionals to it such as "if"

Comment: Oh yes, you can...I'll add another answer